# Transform this game into a Strategic Form Game and draw the game table

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

[image]

> Find the Subgame Perfect equilibrium strategies.

Solution:

Stage 1 : player 2 chooses F after C. And player 2 chooses E after A.

Stage 2: player 1 chooses C.

Then SPNE={ (C), (E after A, F after C)}.

> Transform this game into a Strategic Form Game and draw the game table

[image]

{BD, BE, BF, BG} is Nash equilibrium.

> > ım this question I am stuck at drawin normal form game table. Please help me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answered a similar question. The strategies of Player 1 are indeed A,B,C.
The strategies of Player 2 however are DF,DG,EF,EG.

It is not clear how you filled the table. The (A,F) cell is meaningless: player 1 plays A, and player 2 chooses an action he can't choose.